# Chrome will not play embedded video over a certain width and height

Tags: video, google-chrome, embed, quicktime

I am trying to play a large embedded quicktime video that is stretched across multiple monitors using Google Chrome.  I have been doing some testing and have noticed that it will not display the video if it has a width over 7767 pixels and a height over 1080 pixels.  As soon as I set the pixel width to be 7768 pixels wide then the video is no longer displayed in the browser but the audio will play.

This is the only code currently on the page for testing purposes:

`<embed src="movie.mov" width="7768" height="1080"
autoplay="true" controller="false"  scale="tofit" postdomevents="true"
pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">`

If the width on the above code is changed to be 7767 pixels it will display correctly.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually just tested embedding flash as well and came across the same issue.  making a video that big in Firefox will play.  I am thinking it may just be a chrome fail safe or something for embeds that are too large.  But if anyone knows of a work around I'd love to know it.

Comment: You should file a Chromium bug report. This looks like a real bug, and I don't see any workaround.

Comment: http://crbug.com/38980 may be related as well. As Eli said, please file a bug report or add to this bug.